# django edit profile form does not save

Tags: python, django

The "edit profile" form does not save any data when that is modified.

The problem might be with my get requests or my loops. No error is shown on my terminal when I click "add". It just redirects to the http response.

I might be passing data wrongly also.

**ediprofile.html**

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %} {{form.first_name}} {{form.last_name}} {{form.email}} {{form.phonenumber}} {{form.state}} {{form.next_of_kin}} {{form.dob}} {{form.address}}
    <li class="btnn"><button type="submit" class="conf">Add</button></li>
</form>
<h1 class="cer">{{ form.errors.password1 }}{{form.errors.username}}{{form.errors.first_name}} {{form.errors.last_name}} {{form.errors.email}} {{form.errors.phonenumber}} {{form.errors.address}} {{form.errors.password2}}
</h1>
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Last Name')
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='address')
    next_of_kin = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Next of kin')
    dob = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Date of birth')
    state = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='State')
    phonenumber = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100, help_text='Enter Phone number')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=150, help_text='Email')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Email')})
        self.fields['address'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Address')})
        self.fields['phonenumber'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Phone number')})
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('First name')})
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Last name')})

       
        self.fields['dob'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Date of birth')})
        self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': ('State')})
        self.fields['next_of_kin'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Next of kin')})
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['phonenumber'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['address'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['dob'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['next_of_kin'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phonenumber',
                  'email', 'address', 'dob', 'state', 'next_of_kin')
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_profile(request,id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=id)
    user = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=id, user=profile.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(f'/dashboard/profile/{profile.user.slug}/{profile.user.pk}')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Could not save')

    else:
       
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'core/editprofile.html', args)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the

```
<form method="post">
```

tag, it misses the action attribute,
so when you pressed the submit button, it doesn't send the form back
to your view, it just keeps staying on the page.

To fix this, add the action attribute into the tag.

**Example**

```
<form method="post" action="/url/to/your/view">
```

**2020/10/06 Expand the answer for another bug in code.**

After a further digging of the code. I found that the template missed two fields.

- password1
- password2

Since the form inherited "UserCreationForm" which requires "password1" and "password2" fields. Therefore the form will never be valid until those two fields are provided. Edit the template and form with the following examples.

**Example - template**

```
<form method="post" action="/url/to/your/view">
    ...
    {{form.password1}}
    {{form.password2}}<!-- Add these two fields -->
    ...
</form>
```

Also, modify the form

**Example - form**

```
class EditProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__' # Replace the origin tuple with '__all__' to include all the fields(include password1 and password2)
```

Also, I modified part of the view for better bug test purpose.

**Example**

```
def edit_profile(request, id):
    # profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=id) # Since no Profile model provided, I comment it for testing purpose.
    # user = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=id, user=profile.user.id)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id) # Change for testing purpose

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        # else:
        #     return HttpResponse('Could not save')
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'ediprofile.html', args) # Instead, return render() will prvoide us rich error message when form is not filled in proporly.

    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'ediprofile.html', args)
```

Since no purpose of what this code for is provided, I assume it is editing the data of a "User" model object so this test can go on. After implementing the code in my computer to process a test, it successfully saved and edit the data of the user.

Comment: it still does not save

Comment: I added extra info for the answer after a further digging of the code. Another reason that makes the form not save is because of some fields is not filled. The extra info will provide the detail.

Comment: @blockhead some extra info is provided. Feel free to have a look.

Comment: I've solved the problem. Its a lot bigger than this. I had to use abstract user. I'll upvote, you're on the right track. Thanks for taking your time to answer.

Comment: @blockhead how did you solve the problem..?, please let me know

Comment: @LbAbid I used abstract base user for my profile model